# Getting blank emails through my contact form every day

Tags: php, html

Every day around the same time I am getting blank emails from my contact form, is there any way to prevent this? Looks like bots are causing this problem.

PHP: https://justpaste.it/wdaj (Using a link because it didn't recognise my code)

Javascript:

```js
<script>$("form").submit(function(e) {

    var ref = $(this).find("[required]");

    $(ref).each(function(){
        if ( $(this).val() == '' )
        {
            alert("U bent vergeten verplichte velden in te vullen.");

            $(this).focus();

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });  return true;
}); </script>
```

HTML: `

```
<div class="messages"></div>

<div class="controls">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Voornaam *</label>
                <input id="offerte_name" type="text" name="naam" class="form-control" placeholder="Voer hier uw voornaam in *" required="required" data-error="Voer uw voornaam in.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_lastname">Achternaam *</label>
                <input id="offerte_lastname" type="text" name="achternaam" class="form-control" placeholder="Voer hier uw achternaam in *" required="required" data-error="Voer uw achternaam in.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">E-mail *</label>
                <input id="offerte_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Voer hier uw e-mail in *" required="required" data-error="Voer alstublieft een geldige e-mail adres in.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Telefoonnummer</label>
                <input id="offerte_phone" type="tel" name="telefoonnummer" class="form-control" placeholder="Voer hier uw telefoonnummer in">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_naam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
                <input id="offerte_naam" type="text" name="bedrijfsnaam" class="form-control" placeholder="Voer hier uw bedrijfsnaam in">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_message">Laat ons weten wat u allemaal wilt: *</label>
                <textarea id="offerte_message" name="bericht" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier in wat u allemaal wilt en van ons verwacht *" rows="4" required data-error="Laat ons weten wat u allemaal wilt."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Verzend uw bericht">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> Deze velden moeten worden ingevuld</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Please provide the email metadata.

Comment: _is there any way to prevent this?_ Yes. Check the fields are not empty on the server side too

Comment: If some bots submit false data (which is a very likely scenario), then yes. There are some techniques to fight back using "traps" - an invisible "email" typed field that should be left empty by real uses (Since it's hidden) - While bots just sniff the form fields and pre-fill them in junk (Read more here http://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/11/how-to-build-a-spam-free-contact-forms-without-captchas/)

Comment: Thanks, going to try this.

Comment: @Bart Just making sure you understand that JS validation happens on the client side and its purpose is to give a better user experience, it's VERY easy to change a required field to be not-required, that's why the REAL validation must ALWAYS be performed on the server side too (**Never trust user input** - Always validate it and sanitize the input against sql injection, XSS, etc...

Comment: @AlonEitan Thanks a lot, the site you linked helped me out big time. Got it working now!